# Create Jenkins pipeline via Groovy script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have the following groovy script which configures my freshly installed Jenkins instance:

```
#!groovy
import hudson.security.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.util.*;
import jenkins.install.*;
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration

// parameters
def jenkinsParameters = [
  email:  '{{ jenkins_username_name }} <{{ jenkins_username_email }}>',
  url:    '{{ jenkins_tls_url }}'
]

// get Jenkins location configuration
def jenkinsLocationConfiguration = JenkinsLocationConfiguration.get()

// set Jenkins URL
jenkinsLocationConfiguration.setUrl(jenkinsParameters.url)

// set Jenkins admin email address
jenkinsLocationConfiguration.setAdminAddress(jenkinsParameters.email)


def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

def hudsonRealm = new HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm(false)

hudsonRealm.createAccount('{{ jenkins_admin_username }}', '{{ jenkins_admin_password }}')
instance.setSecurityRealm(hudsonRealm)
instance.setInstallState(InstallState.INITIAL_SETUP_COMPLETED)
jenkinsLocationConfiguration.save()
instance.save()
```

I would like to create a pipeline by using the Jenkinsfile below also via groovy script:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Buzz Buzz') {
      steps {
        echo 'Bees Buzz!'
      }
    }

    stage('Bees Bees Bees') {
      steps {
        echo 'Buzz, Bees, Buzz!'
        echo 'Bees Buzzing!'
      }
    }

  }
}
```

How can I create this pipeline via Groovy script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def jobDSL="""
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Buzz Buzz') {
      steps {
        echo 'Bees Buzz!'
      }
    }

    stage('Bees Bees Bees') {
      steps {
        echo 'Buzz, Bees, Buzz!'
        echo 'Bees Buzzing!'
      }
    }

  }
}
""";

def flowDefinition = new org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowDefinition(jobDSL, true);
def parent = Jenkins.instance;
def job = new org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob(parent, "testJob")
job.definition = flowDefinition
Jenkins.instance.reload()
```